# sysmalloc when trying to allocate memory

Tags: c, tree

I written a program in c which creates the root of a tree and adds a node to the left child of the root, but somehow when I try to allocate memory for the child-node I get

> sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed. Aborted (core dumped)

even though I am not calling the function `free()`.

I'm using the gcc compiler.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "types.h"
#include "functionality.h"

int main(){
    BTNode root=NULL,tmp;

    root=BTCreate();

    BTInsertLeft(root,'c');
    return 0;
}
```

functionality.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "types.h"

BTNode BTInsertLeft(BTNode node,BTItem item){
    node->left=malloc(sizeof(BTNode));
    BTNode tmp=node->left;
    tmp->left=NULL;
    tmp->right=NULL;
    tmp->item=item;
    tmp->parent=node;
    return tmp;
}

BTNode BTCreate(){
    BTNode root=malloc(sizeof(BTNode));
    root->item='a';
    root->right=NULL;
    root->left=NULL;
    root->parent=NULL;
    return root;
}
```

types.h

```
typedef char BTItem;
struct treenode{
    BTItem item;
    struct treenode *left;
    struct treenode *right;
    struct treenode *parent;
};
typedef struct treenode TREENODE;
typedef TREENODE *BTNode;
```

functionality.h

```
BTNode BTCreate();
BTNode BTInsertLeft(BTNode node,BTItem item);
```

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "your error message" )`  to output to `stderr`, both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: OT: regarding: `typedef TREENODE *BTNode;`  it is a very poor programming practice to hide a pointer in a typedef statement

Answer (score 3):

You're not allocating enough space in `BTCreate()`. `sizeof(BTNode)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of a `treenode` structure. It should be:

```
BTNode root = malloc(sizeof(*root));
```

or

```
BTNode root = malloc(sizeof(TREENODE));
```

The general rule is that the type argument to `sizeof()` in a `malloc()` call should *not* be the same as the type of the variable you're assigning to. It should be the type that the pointer points to, i.e. it should have one less `*` than the variable's type, or you can use `*variable` to refer to the value that it points to.

It's also often a bad idea to typedef pointers. See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). The name you used, `BTNode`, is a good example of the confusion it causes; you call it a "node", but it's not actually a node, it's a pointer to a node. You should use a name like `BTNodePtr`, but what's the point of that when you can just say `TREENODE *` to be perfectly clear?

Comment: Yes I see, I should be more carefull about the size I am allocating when I am using malloc, and you are right about the typedef too, the problem was that with BTNode I had forgot that it was a pointer and therefore I was allocating the size of the pointer not the size of the struct. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Typedef'ing pointers makes it easy to make that mistake. Don't do it.